# How to find missing records in foxpro table?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a table like below.

| cAcctNumber | nSerialNo | cBatchNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 120 | 456 |
| 12345 | 122 | 456 |
| 12345 | 123 | 456 |
| 12345 | 125 | 456 |
| 12345 | 100 | 500 |
| 12345 | 105 | 500 |
| 12345 | 106 | 500 |
| 12345 | 108 | 500 |

Now I want my output like this,

| nSerialNo |
| --- |
| 121 |
| 124 |
| 101 |
| 102 |
| 103 |
| 104 |
| 107 |

I did something like this,

```
Select cAcctNumber, cBatchNo, nSerialNo , ;
   Min(nSerialNo) as minCN,;
   Max(nSerialNo) as maxCN,; 
   Count(*) as BatchCount; 
   From Cheque_no Group By cAcctNumber, cBatchNo, nSerialNo ;
   Into Cursor Batches  READWRITE 


Select Batches 
Go Top
nMin = minCN
Go Bottom
nMax = maxCN
nMaxRecno = Recno()


Create Cursor MissingChequeno  (nSerialNo I)

For I = nMin+1 To nMax-1
   Try
      Insert Into Batches Values (I)
      
      Insert Into MissingChequeno  Values (I)
   Catch 
   Endtry
ENDFOR
```

Need to get my missing records according to every   **cBatchNo** . It means **Batch 456** missing ** nSerialNo 121,nSerialNo 124**    and  **Batch 456** missing **nSerialNo 101,nSerialNo 102,nSerialNo 103,nSerialNo 104,nSerialNo 107**  .
How can I get my output?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are N ways to do that. One of them is:

```
Create Cursor Cheque_no ;
    (cAcctNumber i,nSerialNo i,cBatchNo i)
Insert Into Cheque_no Values(12345,120,456)
Insert Into Cheque_no Values(12345,122,456)
Insert Into Cheque_no Values(12345,123,456)
Insert Into Cheque_no Values(12345,125,456)
Insert Into Cheque_no Values(12345,100,500)
Insert Into Cheque_no Values(12345,105,500)
Insert Into Cheque_no Values(12345,106,500)
Insert Into Cheque_no Values(12345,108,500)




Local Array laNums[1]
Select Min(nSerialNo), Max(nSerialNo) From Cheque_no Into Array laNums
Local ix
Create Cursor allNums(num i)
For ix = laNums[1] To laNums[2]
    Insert Into allNums Values (m.ix)
Endfor

Select N.num As nSerialNo ;
    From allNums N ;
    where Not Exists (Select * From myTable T Where T.nSerialNo = N.num) ;
    into Cursor MissingChequeno nofilter

Browse
```

Comment: Here I need to change nSerialNo as cPaymentNumber. When I used above code Not a Numeric Expression. How can I fix this?

Comment: You must use a numeric expression. I don't know what you mean, nor your code.

Comment: Can't I use a string for this?

Comment: string for what?

Comment: I need to modify  nSerialNo as cPaymentNumber. Here cPaymentNumber is a char field.

Comment: You can use cast(). ie: Select cast(padl(n.num, 5, '0') as c(5)) as cPaymentNumber, ...